# How to detect and crop an object from image?

Tags: javascript, python, qt, opencv, computer-vision

First background info;
I will have images like [image]
Images include,

- an object to work (model on image)
- a static line centered (shown in image)
- an solid and easily detectable object (i painted a red rectengular)

Questions,
How to detect and rotate images by centered line or solid object? (90°)

How to crop rotated images starting from object edge?

Note:
I am really empty with computer vision, so i know my question is very silly!
Any language or platform solutions will be appreciated(javascript or python preferred)

Thanks ALL!

edit:rotate info

Comment: In summary it sounds like you are trying to standardise a set of images so that they all have have the same size, rotation, border and possibly even levels (think brightness/contrast). An OpenCV solution can be developed to achieve this.

Comment: @MartinEvans Yes. Exactly! You described more clear. Then, should i start learn openCV from zero, or should i look more specific part?

Answer (score 0):

Use image processing to identify the solid line (you may need to apply various filters, detect edges etc).

When you identify the center line (or ruler - it really does not matter which), you have to decide how much you are going to rotate the image and in which direction (you didn't mention any of this info). Let's say, you decided to rotate in clock wise direction for 13 degrees. I am sure opencv has tools to do so.

And choose the language you are the most proficient (you are lucky as [opencv supports more than one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV)), as it will lower the things that you will struggle while you are dealing with a monster problem: image processing.

Good luck.

**Update**

Your questions are way too broad. You are talking about "more than one concept/task". So, I can't give you a list (I am using the word **list** here on purpose) of example codes for all the concepts you need to implement.

However I ask you this question: what is your aim? To write a custom image processing tool for processing above (or similar) images? Or all you care is to process these image somehow? For the latter case, you may want to check out imagemgick. As name suggests, it does a lot of magic. (Imagemagick is an free image processing tool and [you can find it here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) )

**Update (2)**

Please take a look at [imageJ](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/index.html). **If you can not open this link via your normal browser, try using TOR browser!**

Comment: I am working on teeth model. So, I have two image, before and after. I need to exactly cascaded images to measure and compare changes. Because, between to image shoot, camera or model can be moved :(.  Final comparision look alike [this][1][1]: http://www.abc.net.au/news/specials/typhoon-haiyan-photos-before-after/

Comment: Hmm.. then I don't think imagemagick will work for you. If either camera  or model can move, that brings another hurdle into the pile of problems: model in before image could look "larger/smaller" than the one after image. I still think that there might be some existing tools which can perform that kind of tasks for you (I am not sure about free/open source ones. But I expect there to be commercial ones). Again, my question holds: Is this like a project for you so that you HAVE to write this tool by yourself ? Or all you care is to find a tool and get job done ?

Comment: i have not write by myself. I am open to use existing solutions. So, getting jobe done is first aim :)